# Expose a service from mutiple external Ips in kubernetes

Tags: docker, service, kubernetes, configuration

I need to expose dashboard service from multiple external ips. In order to expose a service, I used metallb bare metal loadbalancer.

I just manage to expose dashboard service from single external IP. I wonder if it is possible to expose same service from multiple external IPS?

Answer (score 1):

i think you do it using ingress and expose that service as the LoadBalancer so it will be accessible form both load balancer or from both end point.

Ingress will create one Load Balancer and your service also create one load balancer so it will be accessible from both ip